# Need suggestion for working Xubuntu theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes, metacity

I just installed Xubuntu. Everything works fine except the window manager theme is broken (the border is only 1 px wide which makes it almost impossible to resize a window with my touchpad). The other available themes with wider borders are all ugly as hell.

I would be glad if someone could suggest a metacity theme with wider borders which fits together with the greybird gtk theme. Thanks!

Comment: Any GTK2 and GTK3 will work with XFCE just get one that you like.

Comment: Greybird theme is not actually broken. It was designed with very small borders to grab to resize.

Answer (score 2):

Greybird theme xfwm in Xubuntu 11.10 is actually hard to resize window using mouse. Recent version fix this problem. Otherwise you can use F8 to resize window.

Other Xfwm recommended is shiki theme

```
$ sudo apt-get install shiki-colors-xfwm-theme
```

It has two xfwm theme. You can choose "Shiki-Colors-Easy-Metacity" to get thicker border.

Answer (score 2):

You can also resize windows using the following two methods which tend to be much easier than trying to locate the grip.  After pressing each of the following key combinations you'll be able to resize the active window with your mouse.

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd>